# How to work with ajax when showing different partials - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

So I was wondering how to work with the link_to method and ajax in Rails 3, when redering different partials.

**Example:**

Let say I have two link in `show.html.erb` and every link have a partial to render.

```
<li><%= link_to "Group1", user_path(@user), { :action => 'group1' , :method => :get, :remote => true} %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Group2", user_path(@user), { :action => 'group2' , :method => :get, :remote => true} %></li>
```

And we are going to render the partials in this div:

```
<div id="profile-data">
 ...render here...
</div>
```

In the `UsersController` we have our call methods for each partial:

```
def group1
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
def group2
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

And of course we have our js files in the view user folder:

*group1.js.erb*

```
$("#profile-data").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'group1')) %>");
```

*group2.js.erb*

```
$("#profile-data").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'group2')) %>");
```

**So my question is:** 
is this the right way to render different partials with ajax? Are I missing something? Do have to route them some way?

This code dosent work right now and I dont know why, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is the the right way to use AJAX in rails, what exactly isnt working? I dont see any data being sent or returned. Also, add a better jQuery selector $("#profile-data")

Comment: @KyleC, thanks I have defined a better jquery selector, it directs my to the root index page..

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly state that you want to make a javascript request in your link_to.
This can be done be setting the format in the options hash to js with: `:format => :js`.

So in your case it should look like this:

```
<li><%= link_to "Group1", user_path(@user), { :action => 'group1' , :method => :get, :remote => true, :format => :js} %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Group2", user_path(@user), { :action => 'group2' , :method => :get, :remote => true, :format => :js} %></li>
```

Comment: I don't think that is true. In rails 3 when you add :remote => true to  an anchor element, it adds a data-remote attribute to the tag, and then rails-ujs does all the rest for you, thus no need for the :format => :js.

Answer (score 0):

The link_to should be somewhat like

```
<%= link_to "Group1", {group1_users_path, :format => :js} , :method => :get, :remote => true  %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to "Group1", {:controller=>:users,:action=>:group1, :format => :js} , :method => :get, :remote => true  %>
```

or if it is a member route and needs user_id

```
<%= link_to "Group1", {group1_users_path(@user) :format => :js} , :method => :get, :remote => true  %>
```

The second param for link_to is the url options so only the url related option go in it, others should be out of the hash or else they will be just passed as params.

Check out more details at rails cocs they have some neat docs and examples

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

You need to have group1 and group2 in routes file

it should be like

```
resourses :users do
  collection do 
    get "group1"
    get "group2"
  end
end
```

this will add helpers group1_user_path and   group2_user_path

I recemmond you to go through rails docs thoroughly

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: You example dosent work for me and think it has to do with that I havent defind any routes for it.. can you please show my some how one define the a route for example 2.